# update the directory name according to user in linux

Tags: linux

```
[hadoop@node2 ~]$ pwd
/home/redhat
```

My user is Hadoop but still, filename is redhat
it must be `/home/hadoop`

Answer (score 1):

You can change a user's home directory with the `usermod` command:

```
usermod -md /home/hadoop
```